# Syntax error in a valid JSON document

Tags: json, node.js, google-chrome, safari, jsonp

I am using Node js and this is how I build my response :

```
response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "script"});
response.write(JSON.stringify({"test":"fail"}));
response.end();
```

The client makes a jsonp request and in Chrome as in Safari I get this error :

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/plain.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'
```

The browser gives access to the response it recieved :

```
{"test":"fail"}
```

Where does the syntax error come from ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client is trying to execute the `Script` resource (it is interpreted as `Script`, not JSON).  `{"test":fail"}` is invalid JavaScript -- try running it in the console.

jsonp requires a callback that is ordinarily requested by the client so that it can be run properly.  You should actually be doing something like:

```
response.write(request.query.callback + "(" + JSON.stringify(json) + ")");
```

This will be emitted as

```
callback12345({"test":"fail"})
```

which is valid JavaScript and will run properly.